# Selectively printout lines from a sequential file

Tags: c, file, text-files

I can make my program print out my text file, but how can I make it print out specific lines? Like if there's something that is the same in several lines and I want them to be printed when I run the program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ){
    static const char filNavn[] = "test.txt";
    FILE *fil = fopen( filNavn, "r" );
    if ( fil != NULL ){
        char line [ 256 ];
        while( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), fil ) != NULL ){
            fputs( line, stdout );
        }
        fclose( fil );
    }
    else{
        perror( filNavn );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you Random Access Files, they are much better than sequential http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438941/comparing-and-checking-columns-in-two-files/13463644#13463644

Comment: Yes several information, like i want all the lines that has the name "bob" in it for example, if you follow me?

Comment: 1) What type of data did you store in the file? 2) What do you want to extract from the file (The complete text, part, are you looking for something specific)? 3) Can you paste the file (or part of it)?

Comment: For that is much better to use a random access file (Cause they are more organized). But in all case . . . All the sequences have the same size? 44 characters?

Comment: Pretty sure yes, 44 chars! Im heading to bed soon, getting late, so ill first be reading your next comment tomorrow, but thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is:

1. Store a slot in the variable `line` ( 44 characters by what you said ).
2. Use the `strstr` function from the `string.h` lib to find the position of the string `line` where the string `"2 - 0"` exist, and if it doesn't exist it returns a `NULL` pointer.
3. If the pointer is not `NULL`, then you can print the line.
4. This loop will continue until the `fil` pointer reaches to the `end of the file`.

   ```
   if ( fil != NULL ){

       /* 44 characters because you said that the data is stored in strings of 44. */
       /* And I will think that you inputed the data correctly. */
       char line [ 44 ];

       /* While you don't reach the end of the file. */
       while( !feof( fil ) ){

           /* Scans the "slot" of 44 characters (You gave it that format)*/
           /* starting at the position of the pointer fil and stores it in fil*/
           fscanf( fil, %44s, line );

           /* If the result of the internal string search (strstr) isn't null. */
           /* Print the line.*/
           if( strstr( line, "2 - 0" ) != NULL ){
               printf( "%s\n", line )
           }

           /* Else keep the loop....*/
       }

       fclose( fil );
   }
   ```

Comment: @Michael Jensen: You could also use the functions in **regex.h** in order to create a more powerful search for the selection of the line. If the lines follow a well-formed pattern (If they are regular expressions - see: [Regular Expressions - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)) you may identify the fields within the line and use them for comparison: E.g.: printing only the lines where BA wins or where RUIN scores more than 1. (here I'm assuming that the scores 2 and 0 are related respectively to BA and RUIN).

Comment: Im still having issues with the program, i can find the certain lines now with the info you gave me, and thank you for that! :) but i want to type it my self and the program finds the lines i need, but cant get it to work, any idea how to help me with this? if you want to of course :)

Answer (score -1):

Just put your condition inside the read/print loop:

## include

```
int main ( void )
{
    static const char filNavn[] = "test.txt";
    FILE *fil = fopen( filNavn, "r" );
    if ( fil != NULL )
    {
        char line [ 256 ];
        while( fgets( line, sizeof line, fil ) != NULL )
        {
            // if this line is interesting (eg, has something "the same")
               fputs( line, stdout );
        }
        fclose( fil );
    }
    else
    {
        perror( filNavn );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you said could be commented, why don't you give him the code to be a valid answer?

Comment: Not quite sure how to do that, with an if sentence or?

Comment: Yes, an "if" statement - like the one I suggested in the comment. What exactly goes in the condition of course depends on what your looking for, which the OP didn't say.